# Shorten JavaScript function events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page as below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  var i = 1;
$('#prev').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: 'id=' + i,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    $('#content1').html(result[0]);
    $('#content2').html(result[1]);
    $('#content3').html(result[2]);
    $('#content4').html(result[3]);
    $('#content5').html(result[4]);
    $('#content6').html(result[5]);
  },
  });
  i++;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="prev">prev</td>
<td id="content1">X</td>
<td id="content2">X</td>
<td id="content3">X</td>
<td id="content4">X</td>
<td id="content5">X</td>
<td id="content6">X</td>
<td id="next">next</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The code works well, but is there any solution to do this in one step? I mean if I can provide content 1-6 a common class `content` instead of specific ids. How can I do this if content cells don't have a specific ids (from `content1` to `content6`and has a common class `content`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to the .each() iterator

```
$('.content').each(function(index){
     $(this).html(result[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use this in your case:

```
success: function(result) {
    for(var i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      $('#content' + (i + 1)).html(result[i]);
    }
  }
```

However, if the `#content` divs do not have an identifier to use, you have to set each one in turn.

You could also use the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) iterator if you could get all the `content` divs in one call:

```
$('div .content').each(function(ind)
{
  $(this).html(result[ind]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have anything else coming in with `result` you could also do:

```
success: function(result) {
    $.each(result,function(i,e){
      $('#content' + (i + 1)).html(e);
    });
  }
```